# Timing of query with mongoose and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, promise

I am completely desperate with this problem. I have a query Array which I stored so long in memory. With it, I call an API, fire my requests and store the result to MongoDB...no problem. Unfortunately I have no control reg. the API-Server and some Econnet/TCP/IP connection error make my app crash from time to time.

To be able to resume my querying task, I wrote all my queries in my MonogDB and I want to track/record the queryState of each query being executed or not.

My problem occurs when I try to get the queries back from Mongo into my method which fires the requests. Due to some timing/async problems (I guess), my queryArray stays undefined all the time and I don't get it solved...

server.js:

```
//TEST
var querymongo = require('./config/queryMongo');
var queryobject = new querymongo;
var queryArray = queryobject.results();
```

**queryArray stays undefined all the time...**

queryMongo.js:

```
    //require mongo model + db connection
    var queryDB = require('./queryDB');

    //constructor
    ...

    //mongoRequest method
        this.mongoRequest = function(){
            console.log("Function mongoRequest called now!");
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                queryDB.queries.find({'SearchIndex': 'All'}, function(err, doc){
                    if(err) return reject (err)
                    else resolve (doc)
                });
            });
        }

    //resolve results
    this.results = function(){
        var queryArray = [];
        this.mongoRequest().then(function(doc, err){
             console.log(doc)
            queryArray = doc;
            return queryArray;
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err)
            });
        }



}
module.exports = QueryMongo;
```

The console.log(doc) in the result method works, but returns all docs at the end of all code being executed. What is the problem here?

I would be very thankful as this makes me crazy!

Thanks

Hucho

Comment: I think you should return a promise or having a callback in your `results` function. Because your `QueryMongo` is async, you shouldn't use it as a sync function

Comment: That is exactly the question. I debugged by code step by step and the problem ist the "then" in my result function resp. the callback. It is running again async...another promise?

Answer (score 0):

So your question is why queryArray is undefined?

Because the Mongo query is asynchronous, and you're executing console.log right after, that is, before you get the results.

```
//resolve results
this.results = function(){
    var queryArray = [];
    this.mongoRequest().then(function(doc, err){
     //////// DO SOMETHING WITH THE RESULT HERE
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
        });
    }
```

Comment: I solved it myself in the end and it works great...if anybody is interested I can post the code...